# CORS origin issue in codeigniter api

Tags: angular, codeigniter, ionic-framework

i am developing web API in codeigniter 3 without rest server, API is working in postman but when i try to access in mobile site which is developed on (ionic3 & angular4) at the same time it give me following error.

Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

when i try to login in mobile it give me error in login api..
http://www.example.com/xxx/api/users/login

Please help me, if you have solution on it

Comment: how are you setting your headers on PHP side?

Answer (score 0):

You should set this in your .ts file in your function

```
 headers: any = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
  options: any = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers}),
  url: any = "http://www.example.com/xxx/api/users/login";
```

and on PHP side add the following where you've set the headers.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

or you can also try giving something like

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com', false);
```

Comment: i already use this in constructor of user controller like  public function __construct() {   header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  parent::__construct(); }

Comment: controller where? PHP or in your service.ts file?

Comment: could you please tell where can i use in typescript?

Comment: i added in service.ts like let headers = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' }); even it is not working

Comment: If you're calling your headers right on PHP side no need to set in your .ts file. I doubt if you're setting headers rightly on server side.

Comment: as per your given suggestion i set on both side even it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to php file after php tag(at the top).its a server side issue.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```